# Comparing two dates (Formatted Date as a String and Current Time) using before method

Tags: java, android, date, compare

I need to use the `before` method in Java.  So I can do date compare code like this:

```
if (storedDate.before(currentMonth)) {

}
```

Where `currentMonth` is set like this:

```
int thisMonth = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
cal = Calendar.getInstance(); df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, thisMonth);
// Do I even need to convert like this to match what is stored in the DB below?
```

And `storedDate` loops through a `SQLite` table where dates are stored as formatted Strings such as "Nov 2013" or "Dec 2014";  yes, bad design I know.

What I need to do is see if the date in the current row in the loop is older than this month; if so, I will delete it out of the SQLite DB (I have that code which is fine).

So, how can I build the two variables where I can compare like this `if (storedDate.before(currentMonth)) {`?

**EDIT**:

This is how the month is stored into the DB:

```
            monthTotal = monthTotal + 1;

            Calendar myDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            myDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, monthTotal);

            SimpleDateFormat dfEng = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
            String finalDBDate = dfEng.format(myDate.getTime());
```

**EDIT2:**

Here is what I have so far

```
private void deleteOldSpecialPayments() {

    int thisMonth = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, thisMonth);

    String thisMonthS = df.format(cal.getTime());
    Date currentDate = null;
    try {
        currentDate = df.parse(thisMonthS);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (!database.isOpen()) {
        open();
    }

    Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_CUSTOM_PAYMENTS, allLedgerColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        SpecialPayment sp = cursorToCustomPayments(cursor);
        try {
            Date d = df.parse(sp.month);
            if (d.before(currentDate)) {
                // DELETE ROW
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    // Make sure to close the cursor
    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: *Why* are you storing the values as strings in the database?

Comment: Well if you have that, why not use that? It'll be a lot simpler than parsing the date. (It also removes the ambiguity - you've got a month and a year... what instant within the month and year are you interested in, and what time zone?)

Comment: Right, so it turns out that's useless. So, to go back to the previous issue: what part of the month are you interested in, and in what time zone?

Comment: @JonSkeet  Sorry about the UNIX time mixup I deleted the references.  I am more of a PHP programmer than Java. In PHP there is a strtotime and strfortime function that can basically convert and handle string dates very well.  I am looking for something like this...

Comment: Whatever language you're using, you shouldn't use strings for date/time values unless you absolutely have to. `SimpleDateFormat` is reasonably capable for parsing and formatting dates, but it's still not a good idea to keep dates in your database like that.

Comment: I understand it is bad practice, but unfortunately there are many users with this info in their databases now.  So it is what I have to use when I compare.  I also added some code at the bottom of answer.

Comment: Right - but my point is that it would be just as bad an idea in PHP. Now, for the third time, what instant in time are you actually trying to compare "now" with? What time of what day of the specified month, and in what time zone?

Comment: Sorry about those two questions.  I guess I haven't answered because I haven't thought that through.  These are on Android devices.  And they are stored in the User's timezone I would guess since I don't explicitly set it.  More context:  The dates are this -- The user sets a payment for a bill in a particular month.  Let's say 2 months from now.  Feb 2015.  When it is Mar 2015, I want to auto-delete because Feb 2015 is BEFORE March 2015 and payment is now old. So I guess I don't know how to answer the first question since only Month's are relevant to the real life issue.

Comment: @JonSkeet See added code to Answer

Comment: @KickingLettuce Parse year. Compare year. If one year is less, that's your result. Otherwise parse month and then compare month. If one month is less, that's your result. Otherwise, they're the same. You **don't** have a Date or a Time (just a year and a month).

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. This appears to be the best way to handle the bad method that I am using. If you want to mark this as the answer feel free

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what value you want to compare. It's quite easy to see whether "now" is later than the start of the 1st of a particular month:

```
// TODO: For testing purposes, you'd want a Clock abstraction to be injected.
Date now = new Date();
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

// Each row...
for (...) {
    Date storedDate = format.parse(textFromDatabase);
    if (now.compareTo(storedDate) >= 0) {
        // It is now on or after the start of the given month
    }
}
```

However, you may not want the start of the month stored in the database - you might want the start of the next month. For example, if the stored month is "July 2015" then you might want to delete the row as soon as it's the start of July in the user's time zone - or you may want to wait until it's the start of August. For the start of August, you could either use `java.util.Calendar` (or ideally [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time)) to add a month to the stored date, or you could parse the month and year separately as Elliott suggested in comments.